# Transitioning from Fulltime Freelance to Full time job

Tags: client-relations, designers, freelance

I am Graphic Designer. I've been fulltime freelancing with a company (say Mickey Mouse) and now I am trying to transition from freelance to a fulltime job in another company ( say Mini Mouse). I am very far along in the interview process and everything is going good so far. However, I was recently informed by the HR of the Mini Mouse that they will be needing the following documents as we move forward.

1. Recent Salary Slips from the previous job.
2. Appointment letter along with Salary break annexure.

Now the problem is since I was a freelancer at Mickey Mouse, 1) They used to pay me through PayPal. How do I show HR of the Mini Mouse salary slips?

2. My hiring process at Mickey Mouse was as follows: I saw an application they had posted on Indeed.com. I really liked the company and the work they were doing so I applied. The application had some preselected questions from the employer at Mickey Mouse. Those also included my portfolio. A week later I heard from them and then rates and work was discussed and that was it. Although they do have a common contract for all the independent contractors they work with but there was nothing as such an appointment letter from them.

How do I show people at Mini Mouse an appointment letter?

Also, all of us know -_- Freelancer get paid on hourly rates which sometimes change as per project. **How do I show them salary breakup annexure?**

Any advice and suggestions are really appreciated. Do let me know if you need any more information for you to help.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi kj... What's the problem about explaining to the new company exactly what you explain in this question?

Comment: A lot of this is going to depend on jurisdiction too. In the UK, for instance, if you work solely for one company, you can no longer be considered as 'freelance' so Mickey Mouse would have had to be paying your NI contributions at least. That would provide sufficient evidence for Minnie that you had been working for Mickey.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but as far as I know mostly anywhere you're not legally obliged to show your new employer any salary slips from your previous job. This has nothing to do with design, might be a better question on [workplace.se] if it doesn't exist there already.

Comment: Also worth mentioning where in the world you are since some of these hiring procedures vary from country to country.

Comment: Tax returns typically show income for the self-employed. Of course, if you aren't in the US.. I have no idea.  And I agree with @Luciano if a company asked for some sort of salary record from my last employer, I'd chuckle to myself. That's **not** within their rights to see such information and providing it merely means they don't want me to negotiate salary.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an appointment letter, tell them you don't have an appointment letter and explain why this is. Show them the Paypal balance sheets or whatever they're called. You don't want to start a new job with some made-up excuse.

Also, working full-time for a single company is not actually freelance in many places, but more like remote employment. Possibly a point Mini Mouse is trying to make by asking for all these documents.